# S3 hosting over CloudFront is serving application/octet-stream instead of HTML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Issue: The S3 static hosting URL is serving the right html page but none of the other URL are working fine. They instead, download my index.html as a file over the web browser. Would request some help here because I've tried all solutions found in my research.

Domain: http://amber.fidento.com (via CloudFlare)

S3 static web hosting URL: http://amber.fidento.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

CloudFront Distribution URL: d35jbnkk7p2igl.cloudfront.net

Using curl -I on each of the above URLs, I get application/octet-stream on the output of 1st and 3rd url and text/html on 2nd.

Additional Info:

1. CORS configuration:

   ```
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
   ```
2. Bucket Policy:

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::amber.fidento.com/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. index.html has metadata set as text/html

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. I'm seeing `text/html` for all 3. There was probably a caching issue going on.

Comment: Thank you @MattHouser. Any idea how to avoid caching issues going forward? I wasted my entire day on a non existent problem.

Comment: You can invalidate the CloudFront cache to remove all cached content. Not sure about a CloudFlare equivalent. Also, use "Developer Mode" in your browser to disable the local browser cache.